# arshaw fullcalendar :  several issue

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

**Hello**,
I am using arshaw [`fullcalendar`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) v1.5.2 (only month view ) for property booking website , its a great plugin but I stuck in few problem, I have seen similar issues on [`google code`](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/list) , but there is nothing clear really. :(, Please help me to solve these problems

Here is [`working demo`](http://demo.offshoretechnolabs.com/myroom5/fullcalendar.php) and [`JS Code`](http://jsbin.com/ubogal/3/edit)

#### What I have done so far

- Fetched events data from two different json files below

  - [**`json_events.php`**](http://pastebin.com/u8QmvPPD) : this holds booking detail which is booked from front end by user; admin can not change any details of these type of events.
  - [**`new_charges.php`**](http://pastebin.com/dSzsFWJh) : this holds special charges events detail ,admin **add/update delete** the new charges for any future date(s)  .
- admin can **view** the details of any event when he *click* on an event
- admin can **add/edit and delete** new events on calendar for future dates or range of dates, that will stored on `new_charges.php`

#### here is my issues

**a)** `I want that only one event  is allowed for a date(s).`

**b)** Currently if user **click** on a day on which any booking event or special charges event is there, then it alerts that *day is booked*, 
**but** after that it will show a prompt box to enter event title,

this is  occured because I have used both `dayClick` and `select` methods

```
How do i stops further propagation if a day already have an event ?
```

**c)** suppose a day 15 january (wrapped by `fc-day17` div) is booked ( I have applied a class `booked` for events ) and now when I go to next month and click on `fc-day17` div, it also alert that day is booked whereas there is no booking
 by examining the code i found that it still have the class `booked` for another months for the same divs

I think there is something missing during `eventRender` methods?

```
does `eventRender()`  method is called only once when initialize the calendar 
or each time when we go `prev` or `next` month?
```

**d)** I have changed background-color for special charges events during rendering events via json file, but when I delte that events, it does not change back the normal background and still say that day is booked.

```
how do I make default background of a date if I delete the events of that day??
```

**e)** `how to hide all events related to previous months?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// a) and b)
// We dont need dayClick event, only select
// I think you created calender something like this 
// var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ ... })

select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    //debugger;
    var events = calendar.fullCalendar( 'clientEvents' );
    for (var i = 0; events.length > i ; i++){
        //If we have 1 day event
        if((events[i].end == null && (events[i].start.getTime() >= start.getTime() && events[i].start.getTime() <= end.getTime())) ||
        // If we have many days event 
        (events[i].end != null && ((events[i].start.getTime() >= start.getTime() && events[i].start.getTime() <= end.getTime()) || 
            (events[i].end.getTime() >= start.getTime() && events[i].start.getTime() <= end.getTime()) || 
            (events[i].start.getTime() <= start.getTime() && events[i].end.getTime() >= end.getTime())) 
        )){
            alert("Realy busy!!!");
            return;
        }
    }
    // If this time is not busy, for example, we promt to enter Event Title
    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
    if (title) {
       //............Adding event into calendar
    }
    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
},
// c) and d)
// This is invoked when we navigate throw the month callender 
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view ){
    $(".booked").removeClass(".booked"); // Remove all booked class from element
    var elements = $(".fc-widget-content:not(.fc-other-month)").filter(function(){
        //We try to find day number witch corresponds to the event date
        return (event.end == null && $(this).find(".fc-day-number").text() == event.start.getDate()) //If we have 1 day event
            || (event.end != null && $(this).find(".fc-day-number").text() >= event.start.getDate() // If we have many day event
            &&  $(this).find(".fc-day-number").text() <= event.end.getDate())
    });
    elements.addClass("booked");

    // e)
    // Hide all events related to previous and next months
    // If we event ends in previous month or starts in next we dont show it!
    if(
        (event.end == null && (view.start.getMonth() != event.start.getMonth())) //If we have 1 day event
        || (event.end != null && (view.start.getMonth() > event.end.getMonth() // If we have many day event
        || view.start.getMonth() < event.start.getMonth())) 

    ){
        $(element).hide();
    }
}
```

**EDIT** This construction

```
var elements = $(".fc-widget-content:not(.fc-other-month)").filter(function(){
    //We try to find day number witch corresponds to the event date
    return (event.end == null && $(this).find(".fc-day-number").text() == event.start.getDate()) //If we have 1 day event
        || (event.end != null && $(this).find(".fc-day-number").text() >= event.start.getDate() // If we have many day event
        &&  $(this).find(".fc-day-number").text() <= event.end.getDate())
});
```

meansthat we select days of current month (`:not(.fc-other-month)`) which satisfy the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) conditions (`return true`) : The days of month equal the days of events

About your code as I said you must remove dayClick event, and your select event is:

```
select: function (startDate, endDate, allDay, jsEvent) {
    // This is my addition //
        var events = calendar.fullCalendar( 'clientEvents' );
        for (var i = 0; events.length > i ; i++){
            //If we have 1 day event
            if((events[i].endDate == null && (events[i].start.getTime() >= startDate.getTime() && events[i].start.getTime() <= endDate.getTime())) ||
            // If we have many days event 
            (events[i].endDate != null && ((events[i].start.getTime() >= startDate.getTime() && events[i].start.getTime() <= endDate.getTime()) || 
                (events[i].end.getTime() >= startDate.getTime() && events[i].start.getTime() <= endDate.getTime()) || 
                (events[i].start.getTime() <= startDate.getTime() && events[i].end.getTime() >= endDate.getTime())) 
            )){
                alert('Sorry this date is already taken');
                return;
            }
        }

        // /This is my addition //      
    console.dir(jsEvent);
    if (liveDate > startDate) {
        alert('This date has been passed');
        return false;
    } else {
        var title = prompt('New Charges:');
        if (title) {
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                        title: title,
                        start: startDate,
                        end: endDate,
                        allDay: allDay
                    }, false // make the event "unstick"
                    );
                    var startDateString = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(startDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
                    var endDateString = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(endDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: './new_event.php?action=add',
                        data: {
                            startDate: startDateString,
                            endDate: endDateString,
                            eventTitle: title,
                            propID: propID
                        },
                        dateType: 'json',
                        success: function (resp) {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                        }
                    });
                } // end of inner if
            } // end of else
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
},
```

**About `viewDisplay`.**
Its is fired every time when we go to previous or next month, and it fired after `eventAfterRender`. If we use `eventAfterRender` and go to month without events we have no effect. The free cells stay booked.
I offer analyse events of current month in`viewDisplay`:

```
function viewCalDisplay(view) {

//...................
// Your code

            $(".booked").removeClass("booked"); // Remove all booked class from element
            var events = view.calendar.clientEvents(function(event){  
                //we need only events of current month
                return event.start.getMonth() == view.start.getMonth(); 

            } );

            for(i = 0; events.length > i; i++){
                var event = events[i];
                // We need only days of current month. We select <td> of calender table (by class .ui-widget-content)
                var elements = $(".ui-widget-content:not(.fc-other-month)").filter(function(){
                    //We try to find day number witch corresponds to the event date
                    return (event.end == null && $(this).find(".fc-day-number").text() == event.start.getDate()) //If we have 1 day event
                        || (event.end != null && $(this).find(".fc-day-number").text() >= event.start.getDate() // If we have many day event
                        &&  $(this).find(".fc-day-number").text() <= event.end.getDate())
                });

                elements.addClass("booked"); //Only for this <td> 
            }
}
```

Comment: I have given all the codes in my Question..will you please look into this

Comment: +1, this will work like charm :) , there is confusing `return` in `if` condition in `eventAfterRender` ?? can u tell me what it means?? i have multiple day as well as single days events both on my calendar

Comment: i dont want to draggable and resizebale the events, even i set `event.disableDragging = true;event.disableResizing = true;` but it still draggable and resizeable :(

Comment: I think in your casethe better way to use `viewDisplay` event insteed  `eventAfterRender` because it fires every time when you go to next/previose monse. `eventAfterRender` event work only if there is at least one event in this month.

Comment: I noticed that `viewDisplay` renders only once, whereas your suggested `eventAfterRender` works fine. but  `bookedClass` still added to the same location of next months. I have written both methods, is that fine?? here is my [`complete code`](http://jsbin.com/ufenel/edit#source).please look into this and suggest how to improve more.

Comment: Thanks a ton. one last thing: I have written `return false;`. may I know is there any reason to write only `return;`

Answer (score 1):

***a) I want that only one event is allowed for a date(s).***

Does this problem get resolved if we resolve the problem B? I mean I think you got it in the dayClick callback, right? `alert('Sorry this date is already taken');`

***b) How do i stops further propagation if a day already have an event ?***

Have you tried to `return false` in the callbacks? Or can't you just use `eventClick` callback? It's more relevant to your needs as far as I can tell.

***c) does `eventRender()`  method is called only once when initialize the calendar 
or each time when we go `prev` or `next` month?***

The [docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) says:

> Triggered while an event is being rendered.

So, I *suppose* it's called each time you go to next and previous month.

***e) how to hide all events related to previous months?***

I think you could just use `eventRender` callback to decide if that event should be rendered or not? (Returning false on this callback will prevent the event from being rendered.)

Comment: b)I have user `return false;` but `DayClick` and `EventClick()` triggers simultaneously

Comment: c) its not called as you mentioned, it set all the custom classes to each date block (div, td)  only first time ( i.e. current month display)